# Циклические ссылки Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть такой вопросик. На сайте имеются ссылки на страницы например:

```
<a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
<a href="/info/">Info</a>
```

Нужно сделать так, что бы находясь например на странице Contact, ссылка на страницу Contact становилась не активной. Для этого написал функцию, но она не работает. как исправить?

```
function no_link( $p ) {
    return preg_replace( '%((loop-link|loop-link)[^<]+)[^>]+>([^<]+)</a>%',  '$1<a>$3</a>', $p, 1 );
}
add_filter('no_link');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
$links = [
  '/contact/' => 'main',
  '/info/' => 'page 1',
  '/info2/' => 'page 2'                                
];

foreach ($links as $link => $text) {

    if (strpos("@". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $link )) {
         echo "<div><font>$text</font></div>";
    } else {
         echo "<div><A HREF='links.php?p=" . $link  . "'>$text</A></div>";
    }
}
```